# hostapd does not work on rpi v3 and raspian stretch

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, hotspot

I am trying to set up an access point on my RPI V3 running Raspian stretch. It has been running this configuraton before but then my SD-Card failed.. I am wondering though if it was really the same OS version I was running because the old configuration does not seem to work any more. 
Main differences - I could not configure anything in /etc/network/interfaces. If I try to set up the static interface I want to run the hotspot on in /etc/network/interfaces dhcpcd fails and no interfaces are configured at all. So now the interface is defined in /etc/dhcpcd.conf, 
/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf looks like this:

```
# Basic configuration

country_code=NZ

# This is the name of the WiFi interface we configured above
interface=wifi0

# Use the nl80211 driver with the brcmfmac driver
# driver=nl80211

# This is the name of the network
ssid=QIFI

# Use the 2.4GHz band
hw_mode=g

# Use channel 6
channel=6

# Enable 802.11n
ieee80211n=1

# Enable WMM
wmm_enabled=1

# Enable 40MHz channels with 20ns guard interval
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20]
#[DSSS_CCK-40]

# Accept all MAC addresses
macaddr_acl=0

# Use WPA authentication
auth_algs=1

# Require clients to know the network name
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

# Use WPA2
wpa=2

# Use a pre-shared key
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

# The network passphrase
wpa_passphrase=secret123

# Use AES, instead of TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

When I run sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
I get the following output:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Failed to create interface mon.wifi0: -95 (Operation not supported)
wifi0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
wifi0: Could not connect to kernel driver
Using interface wifi0 with hwaddr b8:27:eb:2b:34:88 and ssid "QIFI"
random: Cannot read from /dev/random: Resource temporarily unavailable
random: Only 0/20 bytes of strong random data available from /dev/random
random: Not enough entropy pool available for secure operations
WPA: Not enough entropy in random pool for secure operations - update keys later when the first station connects
wifi0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
wifi0: AP-ENABLED 
random: Cannot read from /dev/random: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Unfortunately the WIFI does not show up. The error above - could not connect to kernel driver does not sound good.. 
What can I do to get this up & running ?

Comment: I had to disable dhcpcd, it kept messing up my configuration too.

Comment: Very true. The problem is gone since I managed to set up my network using /etc/network/interfaces alone and disabling dhcpcd alltogether. dhcpcd seems to mess around with wpa_supplicant on the interface allthough it is statically configured. I could see on my wifi router that the interface I had set up for hostapd still showed up as connected. So I guess hostapd & wpa_supplicant mess up each others configuration..

Comment: I had same error. But when I've used https://github.com/pihomeserver/Kupiki-Hotspot-Script for creating a hotspot, it resolved. You can check the script for seeing how it configs hostapd.

Answer (score 0):

Use /etc/network/interfaces for wlan config and disable dhcpcd.  Hostapd working on Pi Zero W on stretch-lite and buster-lite!  Many posts talk about driver issues and most recent posts leave /etc/network/interfaces unchanged.  Comments in this post have it right.  Thank you!!

Comment: It doesn't make any difference with the driver if using `/etc/network/interfaces`. It is exactly the same driver and firmware used.